# How to connect to a GIT remote repository with ssh and IPV6 on Windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, ipv6, putty

I have a Windows 7 setup where I've been using IPv4 and git for some time. I have a machine that I need to access with IPv6 only.

I am able to ssh into the machine with GIT bash:

```
$ ssh git@fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88
Last login: Sat Nov 17 14:09:53 2018 from fe80::e119:5811:40e5:becf%en8
ord2-jims14:~ git$
```

And PuTTY also works.

For GIT, I've tried to set a remote in a number of ways.

```
ssh://git@[fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88]/repos/repo.git
ssh://git@%5Bfe80%3A%3A14fc%3Acec5%3Ac174%3Ad88%5D/repos/repo.git
ssh://git@fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88/repos/repo.git
ssh://git@fe80%3A%3A14fc%3Acec5%3Ac174%3Ad88/repos/repo.git
```

It results in

```
$ git pull
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Usin
```

What is the correct syntax for specifying IPv6 SSH URL to GIT on Windows?

Comment: You are not going to be able to use a link-local address like that. If you use a link-local-address in a URI, you must append the `%` followed by the zone (interface) ID, and all that must be enclosed in the brackets (`[]`). Many things will not allow the use of IPv6 link-local addresses in URIs.

Comment: You also cannot connect to a machine on a remote network using IPv6 link-local addresses, which cannot be routed.

Comment: Actually - it worked, after I re-added the public key to the Putty Agent.

Comment: I tried with % appended, and it resulted in host not found. This might be a difference between Windows and Linux, because of PuTTY Agent.

Comment: It is supposed to be used on any platform when using link-local addresses. There is a difference between Windows and Linux when it comes to what the zone ID is. For Windows it is usually something like `%2`, but Linux will have something similar to `%eth0`.

Comment: "_To limit this risk, implementations MUST NOT allow use of this format except for well-defined usages, such as sending to link-local addresses under prefix fe80::/10. At the time of writing, this is the only well-defined usage known._"

Comment: I hear you but it's not the result on my machine.

Comment: From GIT bash: `$ ssh git@fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88%en8
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fe80::14fc:cec5:c174:d88%en8: Name or service not known`

Comment: If this is on windows, that should be a bad zone ID. I just see it as the interface number on Windows. Something like `%2` or `%9`.

Comment: Now I get it. It is remote address, local interface. Thanks.

Comment: I think if you have the correct interface number, and you use that for the zone ID, it may work. Something like: `ssh://git@[fe80:14fc:cec5:c174:d88%2]/git/test.repo`, but replace the `%2` with the correct interface ID.

Comment: The % has to be url-encoded. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for the IPv6 URL for GIT on Windows with PuTTY Agent is:

```
ssh://git@[fe80:14fc:cec5:c174:d88%2510]/git/test.repo
```

Per [RFC 2732](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt) the colon is not URL-escaped, and brackets are required.

The local interface is appended to the end with URL encoding `%2510` where my local interface 10 was found with `ipconfig`. The `%25` is the URL-escaped % character.

```
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e119:5811:40e5:becf%10
```

Of course, it's a prerequisite that the GIT server has the public key registered in its `.ssh/authorized_keys`, which was needed anyway if ssh command line worked from the start.

For GIT to work with the URL, on Windows, I had to use PAgent (PuTTY authentication agent) with the same public key registered. Also, the URL worked for me if I left out the interface suffix `%2510`, but that is not to standard.

Thanks to [Ron Maupin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3745413/ron-maupin)!